# Azure Data Factory Linked Service for Salesforce (API Access in Salesforce Problem)

Tags: azure, permissions, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to connect to **Salesforce** using a linked service on **Azure Data Factory**, But I get the following error (**connection failed**):

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (80) Unknown error received from SOAP response, potentially a problem with user privileges.
```

I have followed the steps mentioned on the following link (Microsoft Documentation), to **Enable API Access in Salesforce Classic by the Permission Set**, but I couldn't find the permission name: **API enabled**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce
https://migration.trujay.com/help/enable-api-access-salesforce-permission-set/

So I have assigned many permissions and I have added 15 settings randomly (as you will see on the picture below):

[Added Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFbh7.png)

Can you please orientate me on which settings & permissions should I add.

Regards,

Comment: Is this helpful: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/perm_sets_about_app_and_system.htm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup -> Profiles -> (profile name) -> System permissions

[image]

Or Setup -> Permission Sets -> (name) -> System permissions and then "Manage Assignments", make sure it's added to your integration user.

If you don't see the checkbox it's possible API access isn't possible in your org . As that blog mentions - there are some cheaper license options like Group Edition, Contact Edition that allow only the website & mobile app use, no API.

Setup -> Company Information, in right column you should see "Organization Edition"

Comment: Professional doesn't have API access, see the blog post you linked to or https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326486&type=1&mode=1. You'll have to chat with your SF account manager about options, full upgrade to say Enterprise Edition might be expensive but there's API addon or if you need it temporarily (like data migration) they might grant you a courtesy license.

Comment: I had Professional Edition. Now I have switched to Developer Edition and it is working fine. Thanks & Regards, El Mehdi