# Enable API access in Salesforce in trial version for Azure Data Factory Linked Service

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

i have a salesforce trial account , i want to create a linked service in Azure data factory. i got message i need to enable API

[Azure Data Factory Linked Service for Salesforce (API Access in Salesforce Problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977688/azure-data-factory-linked-service-for-salesforce-api-access-in-salesforce-probl)

checking  both path
1-profile- not find options to set Enable API
2-permission set- not find options to set Enable API

however many blog said , go to profile and set. is Salesforce trial account disable to Enable API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for Salesforce trial account, you will not have the API access enabled until they are purchased.  As a workaround, you can get a free [developer account].

Also, the API is automatically enabled by default on the these editions:

1. Enterprise Edition
2. Unlimited Edition
3. Developer Edition
4. Performance Edition

This is also confirmed as marked important [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/salesforce-provisioning-tutorial#:%7E:text=doing%20role%20imports.-,Important,-If%20you%20are) in official MS doc