# Salesforce/Data Factory Authentication Error

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

Need to connect SFDC Sandbox to Azure Data Factory but getting the following error when setting up the linked service and testing the connection:

```
Error code9603

DetailsERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (80) Unknown error received from SOAP response, potentially a problem with user privileges. ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (80) Unknown error received from SOAP response, potentially a problem with user privileges. Activity ID: ba13abc8-5490-4d7a-afd4-cf4d5ddf5e86.
```

I confirm the security token for this account has been reset, the SFDC account has been assigned a profile of privileges where 'API enabled' is selected. I have also tried to pass the credentials through Azure Key Vault when setting up the linked account in Data Factory.

Are there any other permissions in Salesforce required so that we can check if everything is selected?

How can we find out what this unknown SOAP error is?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977688/azure-data-factory-linked-service-for-salesforce-api-access-in-salesforce-probl)

Comment: Yes, I have followed all of the instructions in all links in this post and confirm that API is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As **`API Enable`** is checked, there must be a problem with user access or organization access.

Follow the steps below:

Goto Setup -> Permission sets -> Check the name -> Goto systems permissions -> click on manage assignments

Check whether the integration user is added to those permissions or not. If not, add now.

If the integration is not possible, then mostly your organization or the account using for the operation is not having the API access.

Check whether the organization or the account which is being used for this operation is having API access or not, by visiting **`Organization Edition`**